# Add a css arrow to a ul thats position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a arrow to my `ul`, issue is that the `ul` got `position: absolute;`, i always use `position: relative;` on the `ul`. Anybody got ideas?

EDIT: forgot to mention, arrow on top. like [this](http://cssarrowplease.com/)

Jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yucs5/1/)

```
<div id="con">
    <ul id="links">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​


#con {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#con #links {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: aqua;   
}

#con #links li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

​

Comment: where do u need arrow to be?

Comment: forgot to mention, arrow on top

Comment: Can you post screenshot of desired result?

Comment: edited my post so check it, sorry, ill blame it on that its still early in the day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
 #con #links:before{
    content:'';
    width:0px; height:0px;
    position:absolute;left:50%; top:-20px; 
    margin-left:-10px;
    border:10px solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0,0,4,0.8) transparent;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yucs5/10/)**  ​